# How to make Bayesian-style inference for a Poisson process?

Tags: bayesian, poisson-distribution, inference

I am working on a fleet management software recently. Normally, the arrival of merchant request is a Poisson process. That is to say, on average we have a new merchant request every 10 minutes, but sometimes we could have 2 merchant requests coming within 10 minutes, sometimes only 0.

I am thinking about building an inference model based on the arrival rates of the merchant requests: if they keep coming within short interval, that means the zip-code is busy, if they keep coming within long interval, that means the zip-code is not busy.

This looks like Bayesian inference from my perspective:

$$p(\text{isBusy}|\text{observedInterval}) = \frac{p(\text{observedInterval}|\text{isBusy})\cdotp(\text{isBusy})}{p(\text{observedInterval})}$$

However, $p(\text{observedInterval}|\text{isBusy})$ is a Poisson process as I described above. So I am not sure if this can really be modeled in a Bayesian fashion.

Can anyone give me any insight here?

Answer (score 0):

If you assume that the rate itself is a Gamma variable, you can easily update its distribution by Bayesian updating  (The conjugate prior for a Poisson distribution is a Gamma distribution).

If you use this approach, you'll have to define the event  *Busy* in terms of the Poisson parameter (e.g. $P(\text{Busy}) = P(\lambda > c)$, where $\lambda$ is the rate and $c$ is a cutoff value).